# angular - scroll to clicked element

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I think i might be missing something simple.

I have a container element, and an ng-repeat on the child element like so:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="activity" ng-click="myFunc($element)">
    </div>
</div>
```

What i want to to is scroll the container to the clicked activity (container is scrollable and has a set height).

I tried using $element to just get the offset of activity from the top of the container, and then just use jQuerys animate function to scroll to the offset like so:

```
$("#container").animate({ scrollTop: theOffset, { duration: 'medium',easing:'swing' });
```

But I cant seem to use .offset on $elemnt...

What am i missing here?

Thanks in advance, Gabi.

Answer (score 0):

While I normally wouldn't advise manipulating the DOM separately from AngularJS, a possible way of getting this to work is as follows:

I changed `$element` into `$event` in order to get the target element from the click event:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="activity" ng-click="myFunc($event)">
    </div>
</div>
```

As for the javascript portion, getting the offset of the selected element will get us the location we want.

```
$scope.myFunc = function(theOffset){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(theOffset.target).offset().top, duration: 'medium',easing:'swing' });
};
```

I had to change the jquery selector to be on the `html, body` so that it is animating on the page itself, rather than just a container.  Again, ideally with AngularJS you should avoid doing jquery DOM manipulation like this directly.